# How to populate custom field value for logback?

Tags: spring-logback, logstash-logback-encoder

I am trying to write one custom starter in sprintboot for logging. So that all downstream project can follow the same pattern of logging on adding starter in class path.

For this I am trying to create one logback.xml file and using LogstashEncoder.
In this project I am using sleuth and zipking also so that I can see the traceId and spanId.

Following is the logback.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/console.xml"/>
    <appender name="stdout" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>
            %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %5p [Orders:%thread:%X{X-B3-TraceId}:%X{X-B3-SpanId}] %logger{40} - %msg%n
            </pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <appender name="fileout"
              class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <File>c:/elk/orders4.log</File>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy">
            <maxIndex>8</maxIndex>
            <FileNamePattern>./logs/orders.log.%i
            </FileNamePattern>
        </rollingPolicy>e
        <triggeringPolicy
                class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
            <MaxFileSize>128MB</MaxFileSize>
        </triggeringPolicy>

        <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LogstashEncoder">
            <customFields>{"tenantId":"log-odyssey"}</customFields>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <root level="info">
        <appender-ref ref="fileout" />
        <appender-ref ref="stdout" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

Now If you will see in RollingFileAppender I am using one custom field with hardcode value.
I want to populate its value dynamically from http request. as tenantId will be resolved from request itself.

Can someone help me to solve this issue how I can populate custom fields value dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Servlet Filter that retrieves the `tenantId` from the request and populates the `tenantId` property in the [logback MDC](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/mdc.html).  LogstashEncoder will automatically include all properties from the MDC in the JSON output for a log event.  You don't even need to define a custom field in xml.